# Maximum sum of two elements

Tags: algorithm, sum, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

You are given two arrays each with n integers. Find the maximum sum of two elements. You have to choose one element from the first array, one element from the second array and their indexes have to be different.

A greedy algorithms doesn't work, it has to be a dynamic one and with a complexity of O(n).

Comment: Why does it have to be DP? Find the largest elt in each array. If they don't share an index you're done, o/w find the 2nd largest elt in each array and find the largest-2nd pair that is max.

Comment: Note: an interesting edge case is when both arrays are of length 1 (or, trivially, 0), where there is no solution.

Comment: An even more interesting edge case is when only one array is length 1, forcing the use of the second value from the other.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, this is how I would approach this problem:

Find the biggest and the 2nd biggest element of each array, and keep track of which index they're in.  This should be O(n) each.

After you do that, check all the possible sums you can make out of these four numbers(2 from each array) where the index of each isn't the same.  This will be your biggest sum.  This will take a constant amount of time, and won't affect your time complexity.